# Apps can't see my pictures

Tags: photos, images

Apps like Facebook or Tinder or any other can't see my freshly uploaded pictures (via USB cable)... File explorers can see them without any problems... what is going on? I even tried to post them to my GMail and download, but apps can't see those pictures even after downloading (file explorers like EZ can see them in Download directory)... that really makes me mad... what the is going on?

Nexus 5.

Comment: Did you check for a file called .nomedia?

Comment: Are you able to see other Photos in those apps or no Photo is available in those Apps?

Comment: I am able to see other photos. Seems that new ones don't appear. Like they wouldn't be indexed or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a solution, that someone may find useful:

There is a way to make your photos visible for apps that are not seeing them by just opening the photo in original Android photo app. Doesn't work with ES or similar, has to be original build-in app. After that, photo starts to be visible everywhere.